Using Mapstruct in java how to map toEntity with inner Entity?
I have the following data (other fields removed for brevity and clarity):
    @Entity
    class CategoryEntity {
        private Long id;
        private String name;
    }
    
    @Entity
    class ProductEntity {
        private Long id;
        private String name;
        private CategoryEntity category;
    }

The input is
record ProductDto(String name, String categoryName) { }

The code in Service looks like:
    public ProductEntity processProduct(ProductDto productDto) {
        // find and check it exists
        CategoryEntity categoryEntity = categoryService.findCategoryByName(productDto.categoryName());

        ProductEntity productEntity = productMapper.toEntity(productDto);
        productEntity.setCategory(categoryEntity);

        // do some processing
        // ... 
        return productEntity;
    }

How I can implement the mapper to convert Product dto to entity and use the provided Category entity without manually setting it?
I tried passing the Category entity instance as parameter:
@Mapper
interface ProductMapper {
    @Mapping(target = "category", source = "categoryEntity")
    ProductEntity toEntity(ProductDto dto, CategoryEntity categoryEntity);
}

but in this case categoryEntity.id is used to set result productEntity.id
which is completely wrong.
It's Quarkus project with MapStruct 1.5.5.

What it's meant to do with the ProductDto categoryName attribute? To be set into the given categoryEntity?

Yes. It's input from user: "I want to create a new Product under the existing Category". The categoryName is used to findByName and set into Product's category field.

Keep in mind that the mapping method that takes two arguments (without the @MappingTarget annotation) is used for merging objects into a new one, so because of this any target attribute that matches one of the sources is used for mapping.
In the above (simplified) case, you can reach to the target you want using this combination of annotations:
@Mapping(target = "category", source = "categoryEntity")
@Mapping(target = "name", source = "dto.name")
@Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true)
ProductEntity toEntity(ProductDto dto, CategoryEntity categoryEntity);

The first one is the same as yours; the second is necessary because there are two name attributes, and you have to set which one has to be used for the target. The third one is for not setting the id using the categoryEntity one.
The generated code is this:
@Override
public ProductEntity toEntity(ProductDto dto, CategoryEntity categoryEntity) {
    if ( dto == null && categoryEntity == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    ProductEntity productEntity = new ProductEntity();

    if ( dto != null ) {
        productEntity.setName( dto.name() );
    }
    productEntity.setCategory( categoryEntity );

    return productEntity;
}

Of course, this approach may not be scalable to your case, I mean: to make this implement the logic you want, you have to manually set each conflicting attributes between sources as a manual mapping, and each attribute that you don't want to be overwritten to be ignored.
Alternatively, if you want to keep all in the mapper, you can rely on an @AfterMapping annotated method, transform the interface into an abstract class and inject into this the reference to the categoryService (or whatever) to retrieve the category you wish, like this:
@Mapper
public abstract class ProductMapper {

  // CategoryService injection...

  @Mapping(target = "name", source = "dto.name")
  abstract ProductEntity toEntity(ProductDto dto);

  @AfterMapping
  protected ProductEntity enrichEntity(@MappingTarget ProductEntity entity, ProductDto dto) {

    CategoryEntity categoryEntity = categoryService.findCategoryByName(dto.categoryName());
    entity.setCategory(categoryEntity);
    return entity;
  }
}

Obtaining the following generated code:
public class ProductMapperImpl extends ProductMapper {

    @Override
    ProductEntity toEntity(ProductDto dto) {
        if ( dto == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        ProductEntity productEntity = new ProductEntity();

        productEntity.setName( dto.name() );

        ProductEntity target = enrichEntity( productEntity, dto );
        if ( target != null ) {
            return target;
        }

        return productEntity;
    }
}


Thank you, @Francesco.
These two variants I already checked.
The first is not scalable, as you said. The real data has more fields (version, createdAt, createdBy, ...) - so there is a lot of mark as ignore.
